# my Namespace does not allow Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have the following code:

using System;
using System.IO;

```
namespace Project
{
    public partial class Documentation : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\");

        }


    }
}
```

for some reason, i get the error "Project.Directory does not contain a definition for 'GetFiles'". If i change the namespace to anything else, the error goes away. Is there a way to find out what exactly I am doing in my current namespace that disallows the usage of the directory function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined your own class named `Directory`.  Instead, try specifying

```
 string[] filePaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(...);
```

Alternatively, you can specify a class alias for System.IO.Directory

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using SystemDirectory = System.IO.Directory;

...

SystemDirectory.GetFiles(....);
```